# JQuery Get last from multiple class values

Tags: jquery, class, selector

I have a couple of div's that look like this:

```
<div class="film cars-0317219"></div>
<div class="film wall-e-0910970"></div>
<div class="film finding-nemo-0266543"></div>
<div class="film cars-0317219"></div>
```

Im concerned with the second (so last) class name, but only of the divs that have the class 'film'. Is there any way I can get the last class name with JQuery?

To give you an example of what I want to do look below. I want to make these div's clickable and let the visitor go to /title/last-class-name.html

```
$('div.film').live('click', function(){

    // This returns the whole 'film random-title-id'
    // instead of just 'random-title-id'
    var id = $(this).attr('class');

    location.href = '/title/' + id + '.html';

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('div.film').live('click', function(){

    var classes=$(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    var id=classes[classes.length-1];

    location.href = '/title/' + id + '.html';

});
```

although if you don't already have IDs on your elements, this seems like it would make more sense as an ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great! It used to be the ID of the divs, but i'm at a point where the same movie can appear 2 times on one page (i.e. actor, director). There are more actions in this div that alter the movie's state, which should affect the other divs of the same movie too.

Comment: great thanks!  Agree IDs are better in most instances, but this is what I need right now.

Comment: @squarecandy Not sure if you're using that bit, but please note that `live` has been replaced by [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I just used the inner 2 lines to get the fake "ID" out of the last class... but thanks for the heads up!